# Second derivative test inconclusive, all derivatives are 0, moving critical point to origin, no result?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, optimization, partial-derivative

Here is a function $f(x,y)=x^4 + 6x^2y^2 + y^4 -4x^3 - 12xy^2 + 6x^2 + 6y^2 - 4x + 1$. I've happily proved that $(1,0)$ is a critical point for that function. Now I'd like to decide whether is it a saddle point, a minimum or a maximum. I've seen that some technique that might work is to "move" the origin to this point $(1,0)$. But I don't see how it works.

What I've tried:

I've rewritten the function in term of my new coordinates when moving the point but of course I face the same problem of zero-derivatives. Do I not get the technique? Can you tell me about it?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you mean to write $f(x,y)$ rather than $f(x)$

Comment: Have you tried this http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/RelativeExtrema.aspx method

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, sorry, edited

Comment: I changed $6x²y²$ to $6x^2y^2$ and similarly for a cube and some other squares.  Notice the difference.

Comment: Thank you ;) That's what I've done user121270 but that's what actually leads to an inconclusive thing. Paul's Online Notes say "another method will need to be used", that's what I'm looking for

Comment: Try consider $f(x+\Delta x, y+\Delta y)-f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the method you were expecting, but 
$$f(x, y) = (x-1)^4+y^4+6y^2(x-1)^2$$
may help you decide...

Comment: Riiiiight! Not the method I expected indeed but much nicer, thank you!